# Set Session object inside a WebMethod (using EnableSession = true) not storing value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, session, webforms

I am passing a variable to a session via WebMethod

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static bool lookEventQ(int eventuid)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Q_EVENT_ID"] = eventuid;
    return true;
}
```

Calling it by using jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "<%= ResolveUrl("~/public-conference.aspx")%>/lookEventQ?eventuid=" + event,
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    //DO STUFF
                }
            });
```

But then, on another page, try to access to this session variable:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(Request.Form.Get(CONST_postKey), out eventID))
        {
            if(eventID == int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["Q_EVENT_ID"])){
                //Do other stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when tring to access, the Session is empty

Comment: is your webmethod called successfully ?

Comment: Yes it is.  The method is always being called by the front-end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution. As the asp file doesn't contains a ScriptManager with property `EnablePageMethods` set to `true`, the session not maintains.